# Using DataTemplateSelector with ItemContainerStyle

Tags: xaml, gridview, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have a `GridView` that uses a `DataTemplateSelector`. It works fine when the `DataTemplateSelector` is set on the `GridView` like so:

```
        <GridView x:Name="PayeesGridView"
                  IsItemClickEnabled="True"
                  ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource PayeeTemplateSelector}"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding FilteredPayees,
                                        Mode=OneWay}"
                  Padding="5"
                  SelectionMode="None">

            <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="ItemClick">
                    <core:CallMethodAction MethodName="GridViewItemClick" TargetObject="{Binding Mode=OneWay}" />
                </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
            </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <GridView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <ItemsWrapGrid x:Name="ItemWrapGrid" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemsPanel>

            <GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="GridViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5" />
                </Style>
            </GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
        </GridView>
```

However, I am trying to set the `DataTemplate` inside of the `ItemContainerStyle` so that I am able to use `VisualStateManager`. I tried to declare it like this:

```
        <GridView x:Name="PayeesGridView"
                  IsItemClickEnabled="True"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding FilteredPayees,
                                        Mode=OneWay}"
                  Padding="5"
                  SelectionMode="None">

            <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="ItemClick">
                    <core:CallMethodAction MethodName="GridViewItemClick" TargetObject="{Binding Mode=OneWay}" />
                </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
            </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <GridView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <ItemsWrapGrid x:Name="ItemWrapGrid" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemsPanel>

            <GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="GridViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5" />
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="GridViewItem">
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.Background>
                                        <SolidColorBrush x:Name="GridBackground" Color="Transparent" />
                                    </Grid.Background>

                                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                                    <Setter Target="GridBackground.Color" Value="Green" />
                                                </VisualState.Setters>
                                                <Storyboard />
                                            </VisualState>
                                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                                    <Setter Target="GridBackground.Color" Value="#36B536" />
                                                </VisualState.Setters>
                                                <Storyboard />
                                            </VisualState>
                                        </VisualStateGroup>
                                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

                                    <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                                      ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                                                      ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource PayeeTemplateSelector}" />
                                </Grid>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
        </GridView>
```

Using a `ContentPresenter` and specifying the `ContentTemplateSelector` the same way as the `ItemTemplateSelector` was on the `GridView`. Doing it this way, the `GridView` just displays the object view of each `Payee`. The `VisualStates` work properly, but it is not using the `DataTemplate`s that I have defined.

The `DataTemplates` are defined in the `Page.Resources` like so:

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="OpenPayeeDataTemplate" x:DataType="models:Payee">
        <Grid>
            <Border Width="230"
                    Height="230"
                    Background="White"
                    BorderBrush="#36B536"
                    BorderThickness="4">
                <Grid Margin="5,0,5,0">
                    <Image Width="160"
                           Height="160"
                           Source="{x:Bind LogoBase64, Converter={StaticResource Base64StringToImageSourceConverter}}" />
                    <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Top"
                               FontSize="14"
                               FontWeight="Bold"
                               Foreground="Black"
                               Text="{x:Bind CompanyName}"
                               TextAlignment="Left"
                               TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords" />
                    <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                               FontSize="12"
                               FontWeight="Bold"
                               Foreground="Black"
                               Text="{x:Bind AccountNickname}"
                               TextAlignment="Right"
                               TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords" />
                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ClosedPayeeDataTemplate" x:DataType="models:Payee">
        <Grid>
            <Border Width="230"
                    Height="230"
                    Background="White"
                    BorderBrush="#36B536"
                    BorderThickness="4">
                <Grid Margin="5,0,5,0">
                    <Image Width="160"
                           Height="160"
                           Source="{x:Bind LogoBase64, Converter={StaticResource Base64StringToImageSourceConverter}}" />
                    <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Top"
                               FontSize="14"
                               FontWeight="Bold"
                               Foreground="Black"
                               Text="{x:Bind CompanyName}"
                               TextAlignment="Left"
                               TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords" />
                    <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                               FontSize="12"
                               FontWeight="Bold"
                               Foreground="Black"
                               Text="{x:Bind AccountNickname}"
                               TextAlignment="Right"
                               TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords" />
                </Grid>
            </Border>
            <Border Width="230"
                    Height="230"
                    Background="Gray"
                    Opacity="0.75" />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
    <converters:PayeeDataTemplateSelector x:Name="PayeeTemplateSelector"
                                          ClosedPayeeDataTemplate="{StaticResource ClosedPayeeDataTemplate}"
                                          OpenPayeeDataTemplate="{StaticResource OpenPayeeDataTemplate}" />
```

Alternatively, I have tried to use the `VisualStateManager` inside the `DataTemplate`s, but they aren't triggered, so I am required to use it *outside* of the `DataTemplate`, hence the desire to use the `ContentPresenter` inside the `ItemContainerStyle`.

I do something similar with some `ListViewItem`s, but they do not use a `DataTemplateSelector` so I don't run into the same issue. Is there a way to get `VisualStateManager` to work from within a `DataTemplate`, or get the `DataTemplateSelector` to work from within a `ContentPresenter`?

**EDIT**

Here is the XAML I tried putting in `Styles/DataTemplates.xaml`. The style is being applied, but I do not get any of the `VisualStates` being triggered.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="PaymentTemplate">
    <UserControl>
        <Grid>
            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                    <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Target="GridItemOverlay.Background" Value="Green" />
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

            <Border Width="450"
                    Height="Auto"
                    Background="White"
                    BorderBrush="#36B536"
                    BorderThickness="4"
                    CornerRadius="5">

                <Grid Margin="10,5,10,5">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="34" />
                        <RowDefinition />
                        <RowDefinition />
                        <RowDefinition />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0"
                               Grid.Column="0"
                               Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                               FontSize="26"
                               FontWeight="Bold"
                               Foreground="Black"
                               Text="{Binding AccountName}"
                               TextAlignment="Left"
                               TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords" />
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1"
                               Grid.Column="0"
                               Foreground="Black"
                               Text="{Binding Path=Description}"
                               TextAlignment="Left" />
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1"
                               Grid.Column="1"
                               Foreground="Black">
                        <Run Text="Payment Amount: " />
                        <Run Text="{Binding Path=PaymentAmount, Converter={StaticResource StringFormatConverter}, ConverterParameter='{}{0:N}'}" />
                    </TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="2"
                               Grid.Column="1"
                               Foreground="Black">
                        <Run Text="Principal Amount: " />
                        <Run Text="{Binding Path=PrincipalAmount, Converter={StaticResource StringFormatConverter}, ConverterParameter='{}{0:N}'}" />
                    </TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="3"
                               Grid.Column="0"
                               Foreground="Black">
                        <Run Text="Payment Date: " />
                        <Run Text="{Binding PaymentDate, Converter={StaticResource StringFormatConverter}, ConverterParameter='{}{0:MM/dd/yyyy}'}" />
                    </TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="3"
                               Grid.Column="1"
                               Foreground="Black">
                        <Run Text="Interest Amount: " />
                        <Run Text="{Binding Path=InterestAmount, Converter={StaticResource StringFormatConverter}, ConverterParameter='{}{0:N}'}" />
                    </TextBlock>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
            <Border x:Name="GridItemOverlay"
                    Background="Transparent"
                    Opacity="0.50" />
        </Grid>
    </UserControl>
</DataTemplate>
```

The `VisualState`s work perfectly fine when set directly using the `GridView.ItemContainerStyle` to set the `Template`, but not when trying it from a `DataTemplate` in a separate resource file. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure on the content template selector.
But, your initial thought on using `VisualStateManager` inside the DataTemplates should work.

There is one thing you missed when trying this out, you need to wrap everything inside the `DataTemplate` in an `UserControl` tag! Otherwise the `VisualStateManager` will not work.

Example found here: https://github.com/AppCreativity/Kliva/blob/master/src/Kliva/XAMLResources/DataTemplates.xaml#L21

Comment: I tried to achieve the `VisualStateManager` in the manner that you use it in `Kliva`, and I'm still not getting any changes. I am posting the XAML to my original post so it is formatted correctly...

Comment: Weird at first look your DataTemplate xaml looks correct :/

Comment: Yeah, I thought so too. At least I was able to get it working with the template separated out from the `VisualStateManager`. Better than nothing, I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to achieve what I am wanting by setting the `ContentTemplate` on a `ContentPresenter` inside of my `ItemTemplate`, like this:

```
    <GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="GridViewItem">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="GridViewItem">
                        <Grid>
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                    <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                        <VisualState.Setters>
                                            <Setter Target="GridItemOverlay.Background" Value="Green" />
                                        </VisualState.Setters>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

                            <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{StaticResource PaymentTemplate}" />
                            <Border x:Name="GridItemOverlay"
                                    Background="Transparent"
                                    Opacity="0.50" />
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

And of course, `PaymentTemplate` is a `DataTemplate` defined in `DataTemplates.xaml`. Ideally, I would like to get the `VisualStateManager` stuff bundled together with the `DataTemplate` itself to unclutter the XAML in my `View`, but this way works for now.